# Slow calls to clojure proxy

Tags: clojure

I have an application in clojure making heavy use of a Java framework called Vaadin. Vaadin uses several callbacks using the Java "proxy" feature of clojure. However, every time a proxy is called in a clojure function there is a significant delay (100s of milliseconds sometimes). Is there any way I can speed this up?

Comment: Did you try putting the type hints?

Comment: Do you mean adding type hints for the proxy name, or the method arguments for the implemented methods?

Comment: Just switch on `warn-on-reflection` and put type hints to remove all warnings.

Comment: I added "(set! warn-on-reflection true)" to the start of my clj file after the ns declaration but I got an error "java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: warn-on-reflection in this context (filename.clj:18)"

Comment: That ought to read `*warn-on-reflection*` -- note the asterisks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that the new `reify` macro is faster than `proxy`. You can use it if you only need to implement a single interface.

For example, if you need to implement a `java.awt.event.ActionListener` you can use code like the following:

```
(import 'java.awt.event.ActionListener 'javax.swing.JButton)
(let [a-button (JButton. "Click Me")]
  (.addActionListener a-button
    (reify ActionListener
      (actionPerformed [this ev] (comment do something interesting)))))
```

Comment: For some reason reify would not work on the Vaadin interface com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickListener. Is this beacuase com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickListener is a static interface?

Comment: @Zubair: Not sure. I had to play around with the reify function for a while before I got it to work. The last thing I did was add the `this` variable. What error did you get?

Comment: Actually one can implement multiple interfaces in a single `reify` form. The limitation vs. `proxy` is that `reify` cannot extend classes.